# How to use __autoload function when use composer load

Tags: php, composer-php

```
app/Core
contollers
```

This is my website structure to put the main class, I user composer `psr-4` rule to import class under `app/Core` folder.

#### composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Core\\": ["app/Core"]
        }
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

new Core/Api; // it's work
```

It works fine, but I want to autoload class under controllers folder **without** use `namespace`, so I use `__autoload` function like:

#### index.php

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'controllers/' . $class_name . '.php';
}


new Test // Fatal error: Class 'test'
```

If I remove `include 'vendor/autoload.php';` it will work, so I think the code is correct, I know I can use `classmap` in `composer.json`, but it need to `dump-autoload` everytime I add a new class, how to deal with the conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to use your own implementation of autoloading. You could use composer autoloading for all classes.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Or, you could create class map

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

p.s. indeed, you could use empty namespace with psr-4.

Comment: classmap need to run `composer dump-autoload` all the time, `psr-4` with empty string works!